# Change asp:Label text from C# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been trying with this for an hour or so; just can't seem to figure out.
I have an `asp:Button` on an aspx page, required to complete a couple of functions, one of which is to change the text of an `asp:Label`. This seems like it should be simple and other online posts indicate that I'm approaching the problem correctly but...

The problem is simple but it's killing me. In an effort to debug/troubleshoot, I've stripped the code right back to very basics:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    allValidationMsg.Text = "Original text";
}

protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    allValidationMsg.Text = "Text changed";
}
```

When the button is clicked, nothing happens. I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing.

Update:

```
<asp:Label id="allValidationMsg" runat="server" height="22px" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>

<asp:Button class="navbutton" ID="btnRegister" runat="server" 
                    Text="Register User" OnClick="btnRegister_Click" />
```

Comment: You'll need to show us the markup code as well (the one in the aspx file)

Comment: Can you add the declaration for the `btnRegister` in the aspx file? My first guess is that the code isn't wired to the click event.

Comment: I think Steve Py is correct. Make sure the the button is subscribed to the right click event.

Comment: Have you specified AutoEventWireup twice once in markup and in code behind??

Comment: @ajp.. where should AutoEventWireup appear in code behind..?

Comment: You need to read up about PostBack's and how to check them in C# Asp.Net web pages.. this is what it sounds like to be or should I say first thing that comes to mind..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved; the problem appears to have been with the use of a CompareValidator. Don't really understand why but when this validator is commented out, problem solved. Funnily enough, RequiredField and RegularExpression validators on same page cause no issues..

Comment: Any suggestions regarding why the CompareValidator should have affected in this way would be most welcome. Thanks all..

Comment: simple explanation would be that there is something on the page that you have not validated and or have not filled out or you assigned the causes validation on some control that does not need to have it set to true

Comment: and that is the problem of posting half code - you actually left the erring part out and posted the code that had nothing to do with your problem. There was no way we could have a clue there was a validator unless we see it from your post. congrats!

Answer (score 3):

I think when you click on the Button, Page_Load is called again and the original text remains. Try this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
       allValidationMsg.Text = "Original text";
}
```

Apart from this, I assume you register the event handler for the button in the Markup as I cannot see it anywhere in your code-behind

```
<asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="btnRegister_Click" />
```

Comment: @codingbiz.. Tried this, no luck :(

Comment: dont think so.. in the page life cycle page_load occurs before button handler.. as Puhan mentions it could because he forgot to bind button click

Comment: then put a break-point in the Button_Click handler and tell us what happened in debug mode.

Comment: @codingbiz.. tried inserting break point at the Button_Click handler as you'd suggested. Sure enough, no response (i.e. clicking the button on the aspx page does not fire this code). I've checked and rechecked that the button handler is correctly wired. Can't make sense of this..

Comment: @user1748443 never experienced that before unless the handler registration was not done or pointing to another handler. delete the handler from your code-behind, compile and run. If there are no runtime error, then your OnClick was not pointing to the handler

Comment: @codingbiz.. commented out click handler from code behind and ran as per your suggestion: "Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.interface_admin_registeruser_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'btnRegister_Click' and no extension method 'btnRegister_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.interface_admin_registeruser_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: that's weird. It shows the handler should be called. Now the breaking point revisited. Put the break-point and press F5

Comment: @codingbiz.. Solved; the problem appears to have been with the use of a CompareValidator. Don't really understand why but when this validator is commented out, problem solved. Funnily enough, RequiredField and RegularExpression validators on same page cause no issues.. Thanks for all your help..

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you have forgotten to bind button click to the handler.

You could do it something like that in code-behind:

```
mybutton.Click+=btnRegister_Click;
```

Or in aspx:

```
<asp:Button id="Button1"
       Text="Click here for greeting..."
       OnClick="btnRegister_Click" 
       runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Show you markup and code behind. Is the label visible set to true?

Comment: What about client side validation? I have several validators on this page?  In a similar twist, the Cancel button had code behind to redirect back to home. This is also not happening but the validation is still happening.. Could the validators be causing the problem?!

Comment: I think it could be. Try to comment it and check if it works without validators.

Comment: @Puhan.. Solved; the problem appears to have been with the use of a CompareValidator. Don't really understand why but when this validator is commented out, problem solved. Funnily enough, RequiredField and RegularExpression validators on same page cause no issues.. Thanks for all your help..

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you wrote "onclick" instead of "OnClick" in the markup (case). Possibly it is the cause of the issue.

**UPDATE1**
Could you try to do so (check if postback works):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
       allValidationMsg.Text = "Original text";
    } 
    else
    {
       allValidationMsg.Text = "After postback";
    }
}
```

If the text is changing after pressing the button?

**UPDATE2** Also, please try to make some changes in the text to understand if a new version really deploys (to exclude strong caching issues).

**UPDATE3** You can try to do binding in codebehind (and delete it from aspx).

Comment: It was about update1 or 2? Could you see the "Original text" when page loads?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think I know what it is. In your markup does your label look like this??

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" >Some text</asp:Label>
```

You want this in your markup:

```
<asp:Label ID="Lable1" runat="server" text ="some text"></asp:Label>
```

I have had this happen before. If you change the markup to that. It should work.